# Infinite autoplay pure css carousel

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am looking for a pure css infinite loop moving div.
I have found this codepen, which is mostly what I'm looking for, but I can't find the right settings to make it animate one logo at a time. 
So basically, I want to start the animation, slide one logo in, wait for a 5seconds and then slide in the next one.

https://codepen.io/jackoliver/pen/qVbQqW

HTML

```
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide-track">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
            body {
                align-items: center;
                background: #E3E3E3;
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            @mixin white-gradient {
                background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
            }

            $animationSpeed: 40s;

            // Animation
            @keyframes scroll {
                0% { transform: translateX(0); }
                100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))}
            }


            // Styling
            .slider {
                background: white;
                box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
                height: 100px;
                margin: auto;
                overflow:hidden;
                position: relative;
                width: 960px;

                &::before,
                &::after {
                    @include white-gradient;
                    content: "";
                    height: 100px;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 200px;
                    z-index: 2;
                }

                &::after {
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
                }

                &::before {
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }

                .slide-track {
                    animation: scroll $animationSpeed linear infinite;
                    display: flex;
                    width: calc(250px * 14);
                }

                .slide {
                    height: 100px;
                    width: 250px;
                }
            }
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this, please?

Thanks!!

Comment: You are expecting that when one logo goes from right to left then second should come????

Comment: You can add `margin-right: 700px;` to the `slide` class and pause the animation every few seconds (when the icon reaches the center) then resume after 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet has comment where i have changed the code. I have increased the size of a single slide

link to codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMdeKX)

```css
body {
 align-items: center;
 background: #E3E3E3;
 display: flex;
 height: 100vh;
 justify-content: center;
}

@mixin white-gradient {
 background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}

$animationSpeed: 40s;

// Animation
@keyframes scroll {
 0% { transform: translateX(0); }
 100% { transform: translateX(calc(-960px * 7))} // changes done here
}


// Styling
.slider {
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 860px;
 
 &::before,
 &::after {
  @include white-gradient;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
 
 &::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
 }

 &::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 
 .slide-track {
  animation: scroll $animationSpeed linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(960px * 14); //changes are done here
 }
 
 .slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 960px; //changes are done here
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <div class="slide-track">
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```